Is there a Chef resource to check for version of an installed RPM on RedHat?
I need to find the version of an RPM that is installed so that I can then, via the Chef recipe, apply appropriate user permissions and amendments to specific sub folders and files within the installed software.
The software we have, supplied from an external vendor, has a sub-folder with the version of the software included. For example:

v22.2.0.11

When a new version of the software is released by the vendor, we update the local Yum repo to add the new, suitable versioned RPM, and the Chef recipe we have will then use the standard Chef "package" resource to update the installed software.
The cookbook does not know this new version, nor is there a way to tell it the version prior to running the update.
However, RPM update will not remove the v22.2.0.11 dir if there is content (e.g. log files) added after the installation of that RPM. So we end up with 2 "v" sub-dirs. E.g.:
ls -rlt
total 0
drwxr-x---. 2 user_adm esmgroup 6 Apr 12 13:53 v22.2.0.11
drwxr-x---. 2 user_adm esmgroup 6 Apr 12 13:53 v23.4.101.345
-rw-r-----. 1 user_adm esmgroup 0 Apr 12 13:54 server.jar
-rw-r-----. 1 user_adm esmgroup 0 Apr 12 13:54 server_start.sh

NOTE: This is a made up set of files for this question.
Doing an rpm -qa, we can see something like:
my-software-23.4.101.345-1.noarch (or equivalent)

and using cut (e.g. rpm -qa | grep <rpm name> | cut -d'-' -f3) will yield the version.
Unfortunately, our internal, automated pipeline processes for checking code viability prevents the use of the "rpm" command. I can see why, so I need a Chef way of doing this.
Here is my current (blocked code):
 execute 'Create Version File' do
    command "rpm -qa | grep #{rpm_name} | cut -d'-' -f3 > /tmp/ver_data"
    creates '/tmp/ver_data'
 end
 installed_version = if !node['server']['use_latest_rpm'] && !node['server']['version'].nil?
                       node['server']['version'].split('-').first
                     else
                       `cat '/tmp/ver_data' | tr -d '\\n'`
                     end

  # add the "v" part for folder name info
  ver_dir = "v#{installed_version}"

  config_dir = "#{server_base_dir}/#{ver_dir}/conf"
  config_xml = "#{config_dir}/config.xml"

I need to be able to identify the config_dir and config_xml for each new RPM that may be introduced in the future, but I can't use the "rpm -q" command.

Chef resources are meant to deliver configuration as code, and doing checks is not native to Chef. Not being able run yum or rpm commands will be limitation as Chef also uses platform specific commands under the hood. There is a similar question which might help.

With a bit of work and "out of the box" thinking, I have managed to resolve this by adding a template with a reference to the rpm-q command, and then call that within my recipe.
